# what does exclude in the meta class of django mean?

Tags: python, django, django-models, metaclass

I came across this code:

`drinker/models.py:`

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Drinker(models.Model):
        user            = models.OneToOneField(User)
        birthday        = models.DateField()
        name            = models.CharField(max_length=100)

        def __unicode__(self):
                return self.name
```

`drinker/forms.py:`

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.forms import ModelForm
from drinker.models import Drinker

class RegistrationForm(ModelForm):
        username        = forms.CharField(label=(u'User Name'))
        email           = forms.EmailField(label=(u'Email Address'))
        password        = forms.CharField(label=(u'Password'), widget=forms.PasswordInput(render_value=False))
        password1       = forms.CharField(label=(u'Verify Password'), widget=forms.PasswordInput(render_value=False))

        class Meta:
                model = Drinker
                exclude = ('user',)

        def clean_username(self):
                username = self.cleaned_data['username']
                try:
                        User.objects.get(username=username)
                except User.DoesNotExist:
                        return username
                raise forms.ValidationError("That username is already taken, please select another.")

        def clean(self):
                if self.cleaned_data['password'] != self.cleaned_data['password1']:
                        raise forms.ValidationError("The passwords did not match.  Please try again.")
                return self.cleaned_data
```

My Question is about the inner class meta which as two attributes:

```
model=Drinker
exclude=('user`,)
```

I have a not-so-clear understanding of how this `meta class` work. I have read the `documentation` but I am still confused. Can you kindly explain what those two lines mean and what their purpose is?
Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `exclude` attribute tells Django what fields from the model **not** to include in the form.

Quoting the [Selecting fields to use](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/forms/modelforms/#selecting-the-fields-to-use) section of the model form documentation:

> 2. Set the `exclude` attribute of the `ModelForm`’s inner Meta class to a list of fields to be excluded from the form.

The `model` line simply tells Django what model to take the fields from; together the two lines tell Django to give `RegistrationForm` fields based on all fields on the `Drinker` model, except `'user'`. For the given `Drinker` model, that's `birthday` and `name`.

These fields are added to the other form fields already defined on the form. If the `Drinker` model gained more fields, those would automatically be part of the form too.

See the [Overriding the default fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields) section of the same chapter:

> When you explicitly instantiate a form field like this, it is important to understand how `ModelForm` and regular `Form` are related.
>
> `ModelForm` is a regular `Form` which can automatically generate certain fields. The fields that are automatically generated depend on the content of the `Meta` class and on which fields have already been defined declaratively. Basically, `ModelForm` will only generate fields that are missing from the form, or in other words, fields that weren’t defined declaratively.

The inner `Meta` class is just a convenient way to create a namespace for such configuration on your form class for the Django framework to find. All Django now has to do is introspect `Form.Meta` and see what attributes are defined there.

Note that using `exclude` can lead to security problems. From the same documenation:

> It is strongly recommended that you explicitly set all fields that should be edited in the form using the fields attribute. Failure to do so can easily lead to security problems when a form unexpectedly allows a user to set certain fields, especially when new fields are added to a model. Depending on how the form is rendered, the problem may not even be visible on the web page.
>
> The alternative approach would be to include all fields automatically, or blacklist only some. This fundamental approach is known to be much less secure and has led to serious exploits on major websites (e.g. [GitHub](https://github.com/blog/1068-public-key-security-vulnerability-and-mitigation)).

Comment: `together the two lines tell Django to give RegistrationForm fields based on all fields on the Drinker model, except 'user'` -- but I have other fields for the forms such as email, password1 and password2 that are not in `Drinker`?

Comment: @eagertoLearn: Those are explicit form fields you added; the `Drinker` fields are added too, automatically. If you added more fields on the `Drinker` model, the form would automatically get those too, in future.

Comment: but the form will have only those explicit fields defined in the form for the user to fill in. from where the attributes of `Drinker` comes in for the user to enter them?

Comment: No, listing `model = Drinker` in the Meta makes the `ModelForm` add `birthday` and `name` entries to your form.

Comment: @eagertoLearn: the form should have 6 fields now. 4 explicitly created on the form, 2 from `Drinker`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49686/discussion-between-eagertolearn-and-martijn-pieters)

Comment: please provide your valuable suggestions for this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22388974/django-how-to-design-apps-that-share-models

Comment: I cannot help you there; that question is too broad I am afraid.

Comment: ok, but experts like you can give some opinion that amateurs like us can use to build on. Not sure why it is too broad. my question is about how the design architecture for models. anyway, thanks for looking at that

Comment: @MartijnPieters is it worth updating your answer with the security concerns about the `exclude` attribute in the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelforms-selecting-fields) you already referenced?

Answer (score 1):

`fields = exclude() and fields = '__all__'`  - means display all the fields

`exclude = ('password',)` - means exclude password field

`fields = ('user','email',)`  - means display only email field and userfield

Comment: Seems in the latest version of Django `exclude()` does not work anymore while `fields = '__all__'` works ok.

Answer (score 0):

in short : fields you want to show up in the form should be mentioned in 'fields' attribute ex:

```
fields = '__all__'  #will show all the fields from the model in the form
```

'exclude' does the opposite

```
 exclude = ['title'] # don't show the title field
```